# Debugger will not work when targeting .net framework 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Operating System: windows 7 ( 64 bit )

Visual Studio: 2013

Problem: Debugger does not work when targeting .Net Framework 4.0

I have several windows desktop programs developed in vs2010 targeting .Net Framework 4.0 client profile.  I installed vs2013 and created a test program targeting .Net Framework 4.5.  When I changed the target framework to .Net 4.0 client profile the debugger will not work.

A window would popup "Operation taking longer than expected"  A 64-bit debugging operation is taking longer than expected.  I click the terminate button and a window pops up.  "Are you sure you would like to terminate your remote session?"

Then If I try to run the debugger again, I will get a message box, "Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program.  The network connection to visual studio remote debugger has been closed."

When targeting .net framework 4.5 I did not get an error. Everything was fine.  All the problems started happening when I target framework 4.0.

Using my test program, I tried changing the .net framework back to .net framework 4.5 and debug but now it will not debug in either .net framework.

Things I have tried:

1. I tried removing .net framework 4 and 4.5 and re-installing them.
2. I tried doing a repair on vs2013
3. I tried copying msvsmon.exe (In the remote debugger folder ) from the x86 folder and placing it in the x64 folder
4. I have uninstalled .net framework 4.0 and 4.5 and reinstalled vs2013 several times.
5. I tried a few other things to that people suggested, but nothing has worked.

When I have vs2013 installed on the computer, I can not open visual studio 2010 and run anyone of the programs I developed targeting .net framework 4.0 client profile.  I had to uninstall vs2013 and do a repair on vs2010 to get my programs back up and running.

I've spent the last few days researching this problem, uninstalling, reinstalling.  Please help.

Comment: You have a sick machine.  You need the Geek Squad, not a programmer.  Disable all the crapware, starting with firewall and anti-virus.

Comment: I am assuming you are joking.  My machines are not sick.  Also this is not just happening on 1 machine.  I had to pull vs2013 off the production machine, and I now have it sitting all by it self on my macbook pro i7 using parallels same problem with .net framework 4.0, and this machine is definitely not sick.  Seriously Geek Squad? (lol)

Comment: I haven't solved my problem yet, because I need to install vs2013 on my computer at work.  However, I installed it on one of my computers at home that has windows 8 (64 bit), and vs2013 works fine.  I also have vs2010 on the same machine with no problems.  I can run and compile programs targeting 4.0 and 4.5 framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you have IDM (Internet Download Manager) installed, and if you have enabled "Advanced Browser Integration" in it, do disable that "Advanced Browser Integration" feature. It shall solve the problem. It did for me..!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem.  I found a solution that worked for me on another site and thought I'd repeat it here.

Change the platform target from "Any CPU" to "x86".

Someone smarter than I can explain why it works...